# SQL select all dishes matching ingredient criteria

Tags: sql, select

Im starting to have a headache figuring/searching query to select all dishes that matches some list of ingredients.

My tables:

```
Ingredients
============
ID
IngredientName
IngredientAmount
P_ID


 Dishes
==========
ID
DishName


DishIngredients
==========
ID
DishID
IngredeientID
IngredientAmount
```

Having i.e. two ingredient names, I want to select all dishes ( so I want to know their `P_ID's`) I can make from It ( there will be many dishes with subset of given i.e. 5 ingredients.)

Up to this moment we have following:

```
SELECT d.Name, i.IngredientName, di.IngredientAmount 
FROM Dishes AS d INNER JOIN DishIngredients AS di ON d.DishId = di.DishId 
INNER JOIN Ingredients AS i ON di.IngredientId = i.ID
WHERE i.IngredientName IN ('salt','tomato')
```

Although this will show dishes that require 'tomato' , but require other ingredients, that we dont have on list.

Comment: Can you share the structure of your dishes table?

Comment: Hi, could please show the structure of the "dishes" table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create another table `DishIngredients`, with columns `DishIngredientId`, `DishId`, `IngredientId` and move `IngredientAmount` to this table.
Because, for instance, multiple dishes can have tomato's as an ingredient, but with different amounts.

Then join these three tables to find out which dishes have tomato's as an ingredient something like this:

```
SELECT d.Name, i.IngredientName, di.IngredientAmount 
FROM Dishes AS d INNER JOIN DishIngredients AS di ON d.DishId = di.DishId 
INNER JOIN Ingredients AS i ON di.IngredientId = i.IngredientId
WHERE i.IngredientName = 'Tomato'
```

(And if you want to search for more than one ingredient, use the `IN` clause, just like you already did!)

I've re-read you question, and maybe this is what you mean (any ingredient):

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.DishName 
FROM Dishes AS d INNER JOIN DishIngredients AS di ON d.DishID = di.DishID
WHERE di.IngredientID IN (SELECT i.IngredientID
FROM Ingredients AS i WHERE i.IngredientName IN ('Tomato', 'Cheese'))
```

It lists all available dishes with tomato and cheese as ingredients.
See also this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ec305d/5)

If you want all ingredients, try this:

```
SELECT d.DishName, A.IngredientName, B.IngredientName 
FROM Dishes AS d 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT di.DishIngredientID, i.IngredientName FROM DishIngredients AS di 
    INNER JOIN Ingredients AS i ON di.IngredientID = i.IngredientID AND i.IngredientName = 'Cheese'
    WHERE d.DishID = di.DishID) AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT di.DishIngredientID, i.IngredientName FROM DishIngredients AS di 
    INNER JOIN Ingredients AS i ON di.IngredientID = i.IngredientID AND i.IngredientName = 'Tomato'
    WHERE d.DishID = di.DishID) AS B
```

For each extra ingredient, add another `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Okay, I have rebuild my DB with your suggestions, although my MySQL does not like your syntax : `AS i ON di.IngredientId ON i.IngredientId`  - the 2nd `ON` is unexpected.

Comment: I have edited query to following: `SELECT d.Name, i.IngredientName, di.IngredientAmount 
FROM Dishes AS d INNER JOIN DishIngredients AS di ON d.DishId = di.DishId 
INNER JOIN Ingredients AS i ON di.IngredientId = i.IngredientId
WHERE i.IngredientName IN ('spaghetti','tomato')` however it does not make the job, becouse it is showing dishes that contain i.e. tomato, but same dish require other ingredients, that are not provided.

Comment: Sorry, the second `ON` was a typo, it indeed needs to be an `=`. You can play around with adding ingredients via `AND` and `OR` constructs. I'll update the query to reflect that.

Comment: Man, it's really friday... kept reading your question as ANY ingredient, but I think you mean ALL ingredients. Will update again.

Comment: Many Thanks for update CoolWilly. I will check it see the results shortly !